# Background is sticking to a bone action

Tags: armature

I have just managed to get a simple armature to work. I've done all the weight painting. However, when I activate the image, some of the image on the layers below are activated also. All the layers are in the one Grease Pencil 'Stroke'. Any suggestions?[image: When I raise the beam, parts of the background move up also.]

Answer (score 0):

Select the Stroke object, go to edit mode, select all points of the background lines and fills, select all relevant vertex groups(bones) one by one and press the "Remove" button.

[image]